# Adding an Enter key to the end of scanned data

Tags: c#, .net, motorola-emdk

I have Motorola MC32.. and Windows CE 7.

I intend to use **Symbol.Barcode2** namespace and looking for the setting to set this data modifying rule. 
There is the Datawedge preinstalled but I want to set the rule programmaticaly. I have found nothing in EMDK Help.
Could somebody help me where can I found this opportunity?

Comment: Why you want to have an enter? Please explain. Maybe you have to catch the event and then pass the modified barcode to your Form. But it depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: Barcodes contains number and/or letters just like as you type them on keyboard. After scanning a code without any signaling will not let me know the fact that the user has been scanned - instead of typed - the code. When I receive an Enter key, then I'll know that some code has been arrived and the program have to set the focus to the next field for instance. Without any signaling I can't build in this automatism.

Comment: But you have an event which is fired when a barcode is scanned. So this is your unique signalling. You can fill the current focused control with the scan and focus the next control. So you don't need the enter.